# Resolve user group angularfire

Tags: firebase, angularfire

how would I make sure that the data of the group my users belong to is loaded before the page is shown.

Right now I have added a rootscope variable called currentCompany, and this works fine if I just use routes in the app but if I reload a page then it becomes empty.

I have stuctured the data like the example on firebase.com

All the data users will see will be within their "company" group, so if this doesn't work they wont see anything..

**EDIT 1**

The auth

```
auth.$onAuth(function(authUser){
    if(authUser) {
        var ref = new Firebase (FIREBASE_URL + 'users/'+authUser.uid);
        var user = $firebaseObject(ref);
        $rootScope.currentUser = user;
        $rootScope.currentCompany = user.company;
```

The controller

```
var ref1 = new Firebase('https://******.firebaseio.com/companies/'+$rootScope.currentCompany+'/customers');
var customer = $firebaseArray(ref1);
$scope.customer = customer;
```

HTML

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="($id, item) in customer">
<td >{{item.name}}</td>
<td >{{item.adress}}</td>
<td >{{item.email}}</td>
<td ><button href="" ng-click="remCustomer(item)">delete</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Firebase.com doesn't use $rootScope; it's unlikely you've followed the examples. Reloading the page is atypical for Angular apps--you probably shouldn't do this often. Typically, you also wouldn't wait on data to load before rendering--waiting to see the UI respond drives your customers insane (and far away). This is probably an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), but without code, constraints, and approaches you've already ruled out, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: I said I structured the data like the examples, but there is no example on firebase where the user is only allowed to see content within his group so I have tried that part on my own.
And for reloading I know it's not optimal, but sometimes the pages might be reloaded and when they are they shouldn't be empty, right?
Anyway I added some small snippets to the question.

Comment: How long is this data taking to load? It should be milliseconds to load an object, unless it contains MBs of data. Based on the examples you've provided, Angular and Firebase should take care of showing the data, it should load fairly quickly, and all of this should be entirely unnecessary.

Comment: It loads quickly when i navigate to the page with states but if I reload the page then it is empty and stays that way, do you mean i should leave it like that?

Comment: So this is clearly an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). The problem set isn't how to load the data before showing the page, but that the data doesn't load when you refresh the page. You'll definitely need to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help here. A quick guess: Does $rootScope.currentCompany exist after reload?

Comment: @Stellan Doing this with ng-routes is relatively easy.  Let me know if you want me to give you the solution with it.